# Unique rows after column removal from matrix

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Binary matrix of `n` rows and `m` columns is given. `n` and `m` can be up to 2000.

**We need to tell, is it possible to remove a column, such that rows of the remaining matrix will be unique.**

Example for `n = 3` and `m = 4`:

```
1010
0001
1001
```

Answer is *yes*. We can remove the second column and the remaining rows (`110`, `001`, `101`) will be unique.

Example for `n = 4` and `m = 2`:

```
00
01
10
11
```

Answer is *no*. Whatever column we will choose, rows `0` and `0` will stay.

I [have](http://pastebin.com/vwaSwAMG) O(m*m*n) brute-force algorithm. I check the uniqueness of rows by removing each and every column.

Do you know faster algorithm?

Comment: Do you assume that the rows are unique before removing the column? And do you need to know which column to remove if possible?

Comment: @user3923424 I dont want to know which column to remove.Also their is no such assumption

Comment: Isn't your implementation O(m*m*n*n)? For every m columns you are checking if rows in (m-1)*n matrix are unique. Checking that rows is taking every n*(n-1) pair of rows and comparing them, `testing[i]==testing[j]`. But string comparison is O(m), not O(1).

Comment: The rows must already be unique, otherwise the task is impossible -- deleting a column can't ever make two identical rows different.  It's also impossible if n > 2^m, by the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 1):

!EDIT : My solution is unfortunatelly only halfway to solve this, sorry.

Well I am sure, I can do it in O(m*n) time.

You can create tree in n*m time. Just going one row by one and updating this structure:

```
Node{
 int accessed;
 Node nextZero;
 Node nextOne;
}
```

If you do create this tree, you only have to check the last row, if it has "zeros" and "ones" equal or bigger than two or not.

---

There is a visual example of what it looks like after processing two numbers.

[image: distinct rows]

You just go row by row, always start from root.

For example, when you start processing the second row, you start in root. The number in second row is "101". You take first number, it is "1", so you go into nextOne node. Then you get "0", so you get into nextZero. Then you get "1", which does not exist, so you create it.

After all, you are only interested in the "accessed" number in the most depth nodes, if they all have "accessed" equal to 1, there are all distinct, otherwise, they are not.

---

pseudocode

```
Node{
  int accessed;
  Node nextZero;
  Node nextOne;
}

bool isDistinct(){
  Node root = new Node();
  Node next;
  for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    Node actual = root;
    for (int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
      if (arr[i][j] == 0){
        next = actual.nextZero;
        if (next == null){
          next = new Node();
          acutal.nextZero = next;
        }
      } else {
        next = actual.nextOne;
        if (next == null){
          next = new Node();
          acutal.nextOne = next;
        }
      }

      actual = next;
      actual.accessed++;
      if ((j == arr[i].length - 1) && (actual >= 2)){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

---

Sorry, this is really only "halfaway" to do it, I did not read properly what exactly I am supposed to do. But with some thinking, maybe you can remove a node from tree and rebalanced it effectively...

Comment: Any code ? I dont get you like this or please explain a bit more

Comment: Please can you explain your approach with some example ?

Comment: What you mean by nextZeroNode and nextOneNode ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't always work, counterexample: `00, 01, 10, 11`. But clever, I like it.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk - of course it does, if you have input `00,01,10,11`, you end up with root node, 2 nodes at depth 1 and 4 nodes in depth 2. All 4 nodes in depth 2 wwill have `accessed` property equal to one, therefore there are all distinct.

Comment: @libik And now you have to remove one column. Which will make the remaining rows not unique.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk - oh damn, you are true, I did not read it properly

Answer (score 1):

Each row represent some number in base 10.

1. We can calculate all this numbers in `O(n*m)`.
2. We will get an array `a` of length `n`.
3. We can create an array `b` where in position `b[i]` will be number of times we have number `i` in array `a` in `O(n)`
4. If we have `b[i]>1` for some `i`, the answer is No
5. No we will try to remove columns one by, which will change numbers accordingly. For example if we remove `k`th column, we need to make array `c` which will have the same meaning as array `b` but without `k`th column. To do this we initialize `c[i]=b[i]` if `i<2^k` and if `b[i]=1` for `i>=2^k` then we will update `c[i-2^k]++`. If we get `c[i]>1` for some `i` the answer is No, and continue with next column. Otherwise the answer is Yes. This can be done in `O(n*m)`.

Edit:

The complexity for whole solution is then `O(n*m)`.

Because the numbers will be big, you can represent array `b` as a sparse array using dictionary, and for numbers you can use some library for big numbers. The whole solution should be faster then brute force.

Comment: n,m can go upto 2000 so these numbers are going to be very large .Are you sure calculating them will serve the purpose?

Comment: Also how is it faster than my brute solution ?

Comment: n and m can be up to 2000... Even if we consider numbers in base 2 instead of 10, you won't be able to store this number using a `long`. And anyway, your arrays b and c will be way to big (2^2000=10^602). You can adapt it using a BigNum library to store numbers, and use maps instead of arrays, but I reckon it won't be that much faster in practice because your overhead will be massive compared to the naive algorithm.

Comment: Ok, big numbers can be a problem. I think you can faster get No answer with this solution in comparison to brute force.

Comment: @codetest the solution proposed by Petar is in O(n*m). n*m operations to create the numbers, and then m loops (for each column) that takes n operations.

Comment: `i` is a BigInteger. Thus, `i-2^k` is not O(1). So, in total it's not O(n*m). But, for huge n and m, still better than brute, +1.